# How to get text align center with block but align left?

Tags: css, text, flexbox, alignment

I want this with css `flex property` (**"Image content"** text center align with block but left align) just like a below image.

[image]

**But i got this**

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width:300px;
}
.main {
  width:300px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
  background:#458bc3;
  color:#fff;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.content {
  color:#fff;
  background:#a6d8ff;
  height:100px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
}
.content p {
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="main">
    IMAGE
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
       Image
    </p>
     <p>
       Content
     </p> 
   </div>
</div>
```

I need (**"image content"** text align center with block but align left like image).
Anyone can help me to how to get this approach with flex ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your content the `image` and `content` para's inside `div` with `text-align: left`.

Try this:

Check Demo [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVzgWO)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    IMAGE
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="text-left">
      <p>
        Image
      </p>
      <p>
        Content
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  max-width:300px;
}
.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}
.main {
  width:300px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
  background:#458bc3;
  color:#fff;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.content {
  color:#fff;
  background:#a6d8ff;
  height:100px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
}
.content p {
  margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `align-items:center;` keeps the sub elements of `flex` with `center` aligned. Changing the value to `left` will align left most. Again, you have to adjust the `<p>` element to get your desired output. I would prefer to have `margin-left` with some `%` of value, something like below:

```
.wrapper {
  max-width:300px;
}
.main {
  width:300px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
  background:#458bc3;
  color:#fff;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.content {
  color:#fff;
  background:#a6d8ff;
  height:100px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:left;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
}
.content p {
  margin-left: 40%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.. but text is not align left check your answer. check image which i posted

Comment: You need the "Image Content" aligned left ?I thought you want text align center.

Comment: Yes i need "image Content" center but left align like image, prefer answer with flex if possible

Comment: `need "image Content" center but left align like image` The ask is little confused, can you elaborate more? you mean the `content` div needs left aligned and the `p` inside the `content` div center aligned ?

Comment: Thanks for update but when you increase the `wrapper` and the `main` width it's not remaining the left align.